# how to retrieve values that are fractional from a column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a column named `quantity` with values 1.00,2.00,1.5,2.5,etc. If I want to retrieve the values 1.5,2.5 along with all other similar values how can I write the query?
in `SQL` in have tried:

```
SELECT quantity_billed FROM invoice_line_item WHERE quantity_billed != ROUND(quantity_billed)
```

and

with `like` operator it is giving the values like 1.00 also.

Comment: Why type of SQL is this, [your code works fine for me in MySQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/65f370/1/0)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a MODULO function, too:

```
SELECT quantity_billed 
FROM invoice_line_item 
WHERE quantity_billed MOD 1 <> 0
```

Comment: Ah nice, didn't realise modulo would work like this, massively simpler than what I suggested, it needs to be != 0 for OP's needs though.

Comment: Deleted my answer when I saw this .  Nice.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `NOT LIKE('%.00')` to get fractional amounts. Not sure which database you are using so you may need to modify slightly but this works in MySql and SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

%LIKE% only works for Character string,so you should convert to varchar.if ur data in float or decimal.

**SELECT quantity_billed  
FROM invoice_line_item WHERE convert (varchar,quantity_billed ) 
like '%.5%'**

Comment: In MySQL it's not necessary to convert, may vary by db engine